# Does the possible of Multiple FCM configuration in one android device?

Tags: firebase

Is it possible in one android device in multiple FCM Firebase Messaging_Event service registered ?

Comment: Please try to add more details about your issue and some code of what you tried so far. Add some research details if you made any attempts to define your problem. One line description doesn't clearly help people here to understand of what are getting troubled with.

Answer (score 0):

Only one can exist per device. it does mean that users who share a device will see FCM messages from other users on the same device.